# PowerShell and = inside a & call parameter

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, escaping

I am trying to run the following inside a powershell script:

```
ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner -i .\input.mkv -passlogfile input -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -crf 31 -tile-columns 6 -tile-rows 2 -threads 8 -pass 2 -speed 1 -frame-parallel 1 -row-mt 1 -c:a libopus -b:a 256000 -c:s copy -af aformat=channel_layouts=5.1 -auto-alt-ref 1 -lag-in-frames 25 -y output.mkv
```

This works fine on either cmd or powershell line directly, but not if I try to run it inside a .ps1 with &. I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized option '-hide_banner -i .\input.mkv -passlogfile input -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -crf 31 -tile-columns 6 -tile-rows 2 -threads 8 -pass 2 -speed 1 -frame-parallel 1 -row-mt 1 -c:a libopus -b:a 256000 -c:s copy -auto-alt-ref 1 -lag-in-frames 25 -y -af aformat=channel_layouts=5.1 output.mkv'. Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Digging around a bit it seems that the double = with the -af afilter=channel_layouts=5.1 is pissing powershell off and I have no clue how to get around it. Already tried escaping it in some ways with no luck.

Is there any way I can pass these kind of arguments to my exe without powershell complaining to be unable to split up the arguments? Don't understand the shell tries it in the first place anyway as it should all go to my ffmpeg.exe in the first place.

Comment: Please show exact command, which is falling, preferably as [mcve]. Given the error message, you are running `ffmpeg.exe "-hide_banner ..."`, but not `ffmpeg.exe -hide_banner ...`. Also specify your PowerShell version.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing command line arguments after `--%` ("stop parsing symbol"):

```
& ffmpeg.exe --% -hide_banner -i .\input.mkv -passlogfile input -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -crf 31 -tile-columns 6 -tile-rows 2 -threads 8 -pass 2 -speed 1 -frame-parallel 1 -row-mt 1 -c:a libopus -b:a 256000 -c:s copy -af aformat=channel_layouts=5.1 -auto-alt-ref 1 -lag-in-frames 25 -y output.mkv
```

Comment: oh that might come in handy in another situation, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

my bad. I was just to dump with the output filename. I tried to construct an output filename like this:

```
$show.$episode.mkv
```

which for whatever reason works on the commandline.

the correct way is like this:

```
$outfile = $show + "." + "$episode" + ".mkv";
```

The splitting error just put me on the wrong track.